# CompletableFuture allOf method behavior

Tags: java, completable-future

I have the following piece of java code:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            return "Result of Future 1";
        });

        CompletableFuture<String> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            return "Result of Future 2";
        });

        CompletableFuture<String> future3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
            return "Result of Future 3";
        });

        boolean isdone = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3).isDone();

        if (isdone) {
            System.out.println("Future result " + future1.get() + " | " + future2.get() + " | " + future3.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Futures are not ready");
        }
```

When I run this code it always prints "Futures are not ready". I am using allOf method here which should wait for all the futures to get completed, but the main thread is not waiting here and priniting the else part. Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am using allOf method here which should wait for all the futures to get completed

That's not what `allOf` does. It creates a new `CompletableFuture` that `is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete`. It does not, however, wait for that new `CompletableFuture` to complete.

This means that you should call some method that waits for this `CompletableFuture` to be completed, at which point all the given `CompletableFuture`s are guaranteed to be complete.

For example:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> allof = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3);
allof.get();

if (allof.isDone ()) {
    System.out.println("Future result " + future1.get() + " | " + future2.get() + " | " + future3.get());
} else {
    System.out.println("Futures are not ready");
}
```

Output:

```
Future result Result of Future 1 | Result of Future 2 | Result of Future 3
```

Comment: This works but I am still not clear on the behavior of allOf(). You said - It creates a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete. So how do we know that the new CompletableFuture is completed? Does this not mean we can make use of it rather than waiting for it to complete

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi you have to wait for it to complete by calling some of the `CompletableFuture` methods that does that (such as `get()`). Just creating the `CompletableFuture` doesn't wait for it to complete. Just like creating the original 3 `CompletableFuture`s doesn't wait for them to complete.

Comment: calling `get()` actually blocks it, which might not be a good thing to do. non-blocking methods, such as `whenComplete()`, can be used instead. you can put your logic inside that, which will be executed when the `allOf()` is truly completed.